# SSH default port not changing (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: server, ssh, 22.10

I am on Ubuntu 22.10 and I cannot change SSH default port. I have tried the following:

- Edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, left the default `#Port 22` line but added `Port 1234` below it.
- Then added allow rule for it in UFW using the command:

  ```
  sudo ufw allow 1234
  ```

  which added:

  | To | Action | From |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1234 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
  | 1234 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |

I then restarted the SSH service using 2 different methods (see start of block below), but I saw no change. Service status states it started listening on port 22 and to verify this I checked the listening ports and sure enough it's still 22.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ssh
$ sudo service ssh restart
$ systemctl status ssh
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d
         └─00-socket.conf
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-11-07 10:12:52 AEDT; 5s ago
TriggeredBy: ● ssh.socket
   Docs: man:sshd(8)
         man:sshd_config(5)
Process: 54858 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 54859 (sshd)
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 1020)
 Memory: 1.3M
    CPU: 13ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
         └─54859 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Nov 07 10:12:52 webserver.abc.com systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Nov 07 10:12:52 webserver.abc.com sshd[54859]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Nov 07 10:12:52 webserver.abc.com systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.

ss -tlpn

State         Recv-Q        Send-Q               Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port Process
LISTEN        0             4096                             *:22                *:*    -
```

Am I missing a step or doing something wrong? I do note the service status has `preset: enabled`, but multiple guides I've read haven't mentioned anything about disabling anything like presets.

EDIT:
Thanks matigo for reminding me, but `sshd.service` doesn't seem to be installed yet. I have the config files and can remote in just fine, not sure if I just don't understand and I need to install `sshd` for it to take over the default SSH operations?

Comment: Can I confirm that the service name is `ssh` rather than `sshd`? Generally the server is restarted with `service sshd restart` if you are using the standard server for Ubuntu 

Comment: @matigo I thought that but the default box from linode of this version of ubuntu when I look at the service list with `systemctl list-units --type=service` I only see one entry for ssh: `ssh.service     loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server`

Do I need to install sshd separately? I thought of this but then thought it strange that I have sshd config files and I can ssh in just fine at the moment using defaults.

When trying to do anything with sshd it suggests it doesn't exist: `Unit sshd.service could not be found.`

Comment: `openssh-client/kinetic,now 1:9.0p1-1ubuntu7 amd64 [installed]`
`openssh-server/kinetic,now 1:9.0p1-1ubuntu7 amd64 [installed]`

Comment: Could you edit the question to include what you tried when you say "I then restart the SSH service using 2 different methods but I see no change"? For beginners, the most surefire way to restart a service is probably to reboot the computer. Additionally if you're on Linode then the host may have some backend magic going on and you should probably search their documentation.

Comment: @rexypoo Thanks Rexy, I actually did include the commands in the block just below it. I've edited the post to refer to below.

Comment: Nothing worked for me, I tried eveything below to no avail. After wasting some time, it was a new server install, so I rebooted to try to terminate the running ssh and get it to reset it. Actually it still didn't work, it's still running on port 22!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

SSHd now uses socket-based activation Ubuntu 22.10 or later.
Read more about this change being [discussed here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189/9).

TLDR: The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` are unused, now that I read the comments in full I found:

> # Port and ListenAddress options are not used when sshd is socket-activated,
> # which is now the default in Ubuntu.  See sshd_config(5) and
> # /usr/share/doc/openssh-server/README.Debian.gz for details.

Your options for changing from default port:

- Turning off this change and reverting to how SSHd worked prior to this update (From [twinsen](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/u/twinsen) in discussion linked above):

  - `systemctl disable --now ssh.socket`
  - `systemctl enable --now ssh.service`
  - Then the /etc/ssh/sshd_config works again with Ports and Addresses
    setting
- **OR** Listening socket stream update (from [saxl](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/u/saxl) in discussion linked above)

  1. `mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d`
  2. ```
     cat >/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/listen.conf <<EOF
     [Socket]
     ListenStream=
     ListenStream=1234
     EOF
     ```
  3. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
  4. `sudo systemctl restart ssh.socket`

It should then state it's started listening on the new port:
`systemctl status ssh`
...

> Nov 07 14:42:37 webserver.abc.com sshd[58725]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 1234.
> Nov 07 14:42:37 webserver.abc.com sshd[58725]: Server listening on :: port 1234

Comment: reverting to how SSHd worked prior does't worked for me but the second solution is working perfectly, thank you sir!

Comment: disable socket doesn't work on Ubuntu 23, the new config does work.

Comment: Important: don't forget to add the funny "ListenStream=" line (with no address). Without it it doesn't work -- and doesn't print any error messages either :(

Comment: I don't use funny "ListenStream=" line and I can connect to old 22 port or to new 1234 port... But after I add funny "ListenStream=" line I can connect for new 1234 port only. Ubuntu 23

Comment: after trying the no longer working `sshd_config` method first I also needed to `reboot` to stop port `22` listening

Answer (score 9):

This is how I solved the OpenSSH port issue on Ubuntu 22.10.

Important - Please take a backup or snapshot before you make changes.

Use the nano editor and change the value of ListenStream parameter

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket
```

Change the following parameter to the port of your choice e.g. 44022

```
ListenStream=44022
```

Save the file and quit nano editor.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload<br>
sudo systemctl restart ssh<br>
sudo netstat -tulpn<br>
```

Now you should be able to see that the port 44022 is open.

Do not forget to open the port on firewall e.g. ufw.

```
sudo ufw allow 44022
```

I suggest you open another putty session to ensure you are able to login.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you

Comment: This also enables `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `sshd_config.d/*.conf` to work again. The accepted answer didn't work, tried those two options.

Comment: As @Saftever this worked for me, while accepted answer didn't work.

Comment: Any edits to `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket` will be lost when the package is updated

Answer (score 4):

> SSHd now uses socket-based activation Ubuntu 22.10 or later. Read more about this change being discussed here.

For my purposes adding a socket handler is a complication that we do not want, so we are adding the following to our pre-ansible installation steps to remove ssh.socket and go back to using the sshd_config file.  (Some of these were not previously documented, so this might save someone else some time.)

**Previously we would do the following post-build.**

add line "Port 4022" after "#Port 22" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
then

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

**It looks like the following was required on a new ubuntu 20.10 (Mate 20.10) installation.**

add line "Port 4022" after "#Port 22" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
then

```
sudo systemctl disable --now ssh.socket
sudo systemctl enable --now ssh.service
sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/00-socket.conf ./save_disable_ssh.service.d_00-socket.conf
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl stop ssh
sudo systemctl stop ssh.socket
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

ymmv

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps from others but nothing worked,... until I uninstalled `openssh-server` and then ***reinstalled*** it, along with `ssh`.

1. ```
   mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d
   ```
2. ```
   nano /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/listen.conf
   ```

   ```
   [Socket]
   ListenStream=
   ListenStream=1234
   ```
3. ```
   sudo apt remove --purge openssh-server
   ```
4. ```
   sudo apt install openssh-server ssh
   ```
5. ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
6. ```
   sudo systemctl restart ssh
   ```

After this, running `sudo systemctl status ssh` should show you are listening on the ports originally setup.

```
Feb 21 19:28:08 Computer systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Feb 21 19:28:08 Computer sshd[48455]: Server listening on :: port 1234.
Feb 21 19:28:08 Computer systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

I do not understand why but I wonder if there was some daemon that did not want to be restarted/reloaded or killed, but uninstalling and reinstalling forced that and therefore picked up the new configuration changes. Very ugly.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on 23.04, none of the others did. For whatever reason, the reinstall is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

@Silently is right, probably... But `systemctl disable --now ssh.socket ; systemctl enable --now ssh.service` method doesn't work for me. I don't care why Ubuntu team decided to break SSHD severely, they do it wrong regardless of their intentions: only that odd "Listening socket stream update" method works!

Update: the topic starter didn't mention that you should do it in a slightly different way:

1. ```
   mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d
   ```
2. ```
   cat > /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/listen.conf << EOF
   [Socket]
   ListenStream=
   ListenStream=1234
   EOF
   ```
3. Change SSHD port one way or another (I added `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/local.conf` with `Port 1234`)
4. `[sudo] systemctl daemon-reload`
5. `[sudo] systemctl restart ssh`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answers to this question today (2023-02-14), and still was getting a SSH service being spawned on ipv6, even though I had set `AcceptFamily inet` and `ListenAddress 10.0.2.15:2022` configured on my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on Ubuntu 22.10, then configured `listen.conf` with the different port.

Well, I traced this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1993478/comments/14 which let me to the script on https://launchpadlibrarian.net/630622842/openssh_9.0p1-1ubuntu8.debdiff

which hinted the solution for me. So, if you need a basic configuration of a single ipv4 address listening on a custom port (e.g. `10.0.2.15` on `22022`), do this:

- Erase all `Port` and `ListenAddress` information on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Create the directory `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d` (i.e. `sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d`)
- Put this content to the `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/addresses.conf` file:

---

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=10.0.2.15:2022
```

HINT: Do **not** put `Accept=yes` on this configuration, hoping for the OS to spawn a ssh service on connection demand. On a new Ubuntu 22.10 installation and configuration as in this answer, this made the ssh service to listen on `0.0.0.0` port `22`, and even worse not starting the service on boot.

Then issue these commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl disable ssh.socket
systemctl stop ssh.socket
systemctl enable ssh.service
systemctl start ssh.service
```