# Can’t change SSH port

Tags: 22.04, openssh, sshd

I can’t change the port from 22 for openssh. I’m using `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The line hasn’t been commented out. I’ve restarted the service. But no matter what I do when I check with `service ssh status` or `lsof`, it still uses port 22. I’m on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Have you configured your system to use the newer [socket based activation](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189) method?

Comment: SSHd now uses socket-based activation maybe this is the cause: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439461/ssh-default-port-not-changing-ubuntu-22-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439461/ssh-default-port-not-changing-ubuntu-22-10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH default port not changing (Ubuntu 22.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439461/ssh-default-port-not-changing-ubuntu-22-10)