# SSH configured ports not working

Tags: ssh, firewall, ufw

Just installed Kubunut 22.10. I configured my /etc/ssh/sshd_config with a custom port.

```
# Snip
Port 5555
AllowUsers bob
# Snip
```

Then restart the daemon to refresh the configuration:

`sudo ufw allow 5555`

`sudo systemctl restart ssh`

Everything else is default. I have been doing this configuration setup for a decade. Now when I have another system that cannot connect to it. I get the message:

`ssh -p 5555 bob@192.168.254.11`

I get the error message:

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.254.11 port 5555: Connection refused`

If I use the default use the default port **22** the connection works. I have rebooted and the problem persists. I have turned-off / disabled **ufw**. I have tested with both passwords and SSH-keys, but the connection is refused if I don't use the port 22.

Please help? I don't understand why this suddenly broke.

Comment: It's likely the socket-based activation rather than a firewall issue - see [SSH default port not changing (Ubuntu 22.10)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439482/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver That is very insightful and helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to enable ufw logging and have a look inside /var/log/ufw.log?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in this thread [SSH default port not changing (Ubuntu 22.10)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439482/178692), and they did not work until I did *one extra step*.

I followed the steps from others but nothing worked,... until I uninstalled `openssh-server` and then ***reinstalled*** it, along with `ssh`.

1. mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d
2. nano /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/listen.conf

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=1234
```

3. sudo apt remove --purge openssh-server
4. sudo apt install openssh-server ssh
5. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
6. sudo systemctl restart ssh

After this, running `sudo systemctl status ssh` should show you are listening on the ports originally setup.

```
Feb 21 19:28:08 Computer systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Feb 21 19:28:08 Computer sshd[48455]: Server listening on :: port 1234.
Feb 21 19:28:08 Computer systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

I do not understand why but I wonder if there was some daemon that did not want to be restarted/reloaded or killed, but uninstalling and reinstalling forced that and therefore picked up the new configuration changes.