# I am unable to ssh into my computer using the public IP. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to ssh into my computer from an external source using my public IP address.  but keep getting the error message `ssh: connect to host <public_ip> port 2222: Connection refused`.

#### What fails

1. If I try to ssh from an external IP, into my local computer with `ssh -p 2222 <user_name>@<public_ip>` then this command hangs.
2. If I try to ssh into my computer from my computer itself with  `ssh -p 2222 <user_name>@<public_ip>` then I receive the error message `ssh: connect to host <public_ip> port 2222: Connection refused`.

#### What works

1. I can into my own computer from my computer with `ssh -p 2222 <user_name>@<internal_ip>`
2. I can into my own computer from my mac within the same network with `ssh -p 2222 <user_name>@<internal_ip>`
3. I can ping my public ip address from an computer on an external from my network.

#### Here is what I have done:

1. I have logged into the netgear genie at routerlogin.net and set a port forward to to port 2222 directed to my computer's internal IP address.
2. `systemctl status sshd` returns

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-10-23 14:44:09 PDT; 19min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 305357 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 305359 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38023)
     Memory: 1.7M
        CPU: 23ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─305359 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Oct 23 14:44:09 lenovo systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct 23 14:44:09 lenovo sshd[305359]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
Oct 23 14:44:09 lenovo sshd[305359]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 23 14:44:09 lenovo systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

So my computer is listening to port 2222

3. `systemctl status ufw`

```
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-10-22 20:48:44 PDT; 18h ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 725 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 725 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 36ms

Oct 22 20:48:43 lenovo systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
Oct 22 20:48:44 lenovo systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
```

4. I have run `sudo ufw allow 2222/tcp` and `ufw stats` returns

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
2222/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2222/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

5. I have added `Port 2222` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
6. `nmap -O -v <your public_IP>` returns the follwoing

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   filtered ssh
23/tcp   filtered telnet
80/tcp   filtered http
111/tcp  filtered rpcbind
443/tcp  filtered https
2222/tcp filtered EtherNetIP-1
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy
8181/tcp filtered intermapper
9000/tcp filtered cslistener
```

What else am I missing here?

#### <s>Solution</s>

<s>So I figured out the problem. My network has a double NAT and need to set up port forwarding on both my router and my modem. On my modem, I had to port forward to my router and on my router I had to port forward to my device. I set this up and restarted the modem and now I am able to ssh into my device from an external IP address. Another thing that I think messed me up was that I dont have a static internal IP address so I needed to change the router's port forward to my device since during some of the modem reboots, my internal IP address changed.</s>

Comment: From a terminal that receives a connection refused error, run nmap -O -v <your public_IP>.  This will tell you what ports are open and responding.  The results should tell you how to proceed to fix your issue.  I'm guessing you are being blocked at the router.

Comment: "*I can [ssh] into my own computer from my mac within the same network with ssh -p 2222 <user_name>@<internal_ip>*" You have clearly demonstrated that there is nothing wrong with your Ubuntu opnssh-server. It's working. Your problem is elsewhere: Most commonly it's your router's port forwarding. Lest commonly some ISPs block ssh.

Comment: "What fails": Your server doesn't know it's public IP, so SSH connection attempts from within the LAN using the public IP are expected to fail.

Comment: @user535733 I didnt know that SSH inside the LAN would fail, I did test externally though and it still failed. I don't believe my ISP blocks port 22 or port 2222 as I just checked their website. As far as the port forwarding, I am not sure what else there is to do. I have checked multiple source and each has the same set of instructions to set up a port forward to my computer and thats what I did.

Comment: See this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462010/ssh-connection-refused-on-custom-port-2222).

Comment: @user535733 So I have made a tiny bit of progress, I restarted my modem and now when I try `ssh -p 2222 <username>@<local ip>`, I get the error that says `Connection refused` instead of just hanging. It appears that everything should allow access to this port though. Do you know where I should look to figure this out now?

Comment: You earlier wrote that `ssh -p 2222 <username>@<local ip>` worked properly on the LAN. It's supposed to fail across the internet. Connection Refused by some random machine that happens to have an IP address conflict seems like expected behavior - you don't have an account on that random machine. Across the internet, you should be using `<public ip>`

Comment: If you are actually on the LAN, you should be using `<local IP>`. In that case, Connection Refused suggests that perhaps your server's IP address changed. Using DHCP, a router reboot may indeed change some of the IP addresses. A modem reboot might change your `<public ip>` address (in which case, you're back to connecting to some stranger's server)

Comment: If your ISP is blocking port 2222, as it appears, you can try a different port. Pick some other random port and forward that to your internal IP on port 2222. Nonetheless, have you called your ISP and asked if they block all ports? You can certainly ask them if any are open. If not, perhaps they can unblock a particular port for you.

Comment: So the following in my answer solved your problem :)  Note that the ListenAddress needs to be reachable from the Internet (for your purposes), via NAT or an assigned public IP address.

Comment: This is a question answer site. **Please don't put the answer inside the question.** Click on the Answer your own question button below and put the answer there. Then you should accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green.

Answer (score 1):

From a terminal that receives a connection refused error, run

```
nmap -O -v <your public_IP>
```

This will tell you what ports are open and responding. The results should tell you how to proceed to fix your issue. If port 22 and 2222 answer up have a look at the ssh configuration files on your openssh server.  You should also consider focusing on getting port 22 to work and ditch the forwarding to port 2222 step temporarily.

In the config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sshd_config.conf`, set `loglevel INFO` and then `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a shell on the server to see if anything about the login attempt is logged. Note (and this could be your problem) you will need to create a similar entry for port 2222 in this config file.  Note that the ListenAddress needs to be reachable from the Internet (for your purposes), via NAT or an assigned public IP address.

For troubleshooting purposes, consider setting `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0`

The use of AllowUsers and DenyUsers is a great security feature that should be utilized.  That and the port forwarding you are doing will really cut down on the chances of being hacked.

Sample:

```
Port 22
          ListenAddress 192.168.1.1
          HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
          ServerKeyBits 1024
          LoginGraceTime 600
          KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
          PermitRootLogin no
          IgnoreRhosts yes
          IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
          StrictModes yes
          X11Forwarding no
          PrintMotd yes
          SyslogFacility AUTH
          LogLevel INFO
          RhostsAuthentication no
          RhostsRSAAuthentication no
          RSAAuthentication yes
          PasswordAuthentication yes
          PermitEmptyPasswords no
          AllowUsers your_username
```

Based on your symptoms I doubt you are getting this far but check/clear `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` on the client you are using to ssh in to the server and see if keys are being exchanged.  Again, I would modify the openssh server and your router to only use port 22 for ssh.  Once you get that working you can add the additional security of using a different port.  You should also disable telnet/ftp and only allow `ssh` and `sftp` for better security.

Comment: I edited the post with part of the output of this command.

Comment: Whats the purpose of `ListenAddress 192.168.1.1`? Right now in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, the `ListenAddress` line is commented out.

Comment: The 192 addy was simply an example.  I suggested setting it to 0.0.0.0 which is the default, simply to eliminate a listening socket problem from the process.  You seem to have a good handle on how networking works so my answer was more geared towards giving you ideas on how to troubleshoot and eliminate possible problems.  On it's face, the situation you described could not exist.  So I wanted to get you to reduce the complication of the test environment.  No one here would have guessed the cause was a double NAT addy.  Which is why I said that the listening addy must be reachable.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem. My network has a double NAT and need to set up port forwarding on both my router and my modem. On my modem, I had to port forward to my router and on my router I had to port forward to my device. I set this up and restarted the modem and now I am able to ssh into my device from an external IP address. Another thing that I think messed me up was that I dont have a static internal IP address so I needed to change the router's port forward to my device since during some of the modem reboots, my internal IP address changed