# How to change the ssh port on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: ssh

How to change the ssh port on Ubuntu 23.04?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve. If you want/need to use a different port number at your public IP address, you could configure this in the port forwarding of your router.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH default port not changing (Ubuntu 22.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439461/ssh-default-port-not-changing-ubuntu-22-10)

Answer (score 4):

In **`Ubuntu 22`** and mostly in **`Ubuntu 23`** if we change ssh port in sshd_config it doesn't work so I figured it out following method

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket
```

Change the following parameter to the port of your choice e.g. 1122

```
ListenStream=1122
```

Save the file and quit the `vim` editor with the command `wq!` and then execute the following commands one by one

This will reload the daemon

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

To restart the SSH server

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

and if you want to check the port you can check with the following command `netstat -ant |grep 6381`

in case you you face the error `Command 'netstat' not found`

you can be installed with: `apt install net-tools -y`

Comment: Any edits to `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket` will be lost when the package is updated. Use override files to change settings instead.

Comment: which files i tried updating in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but didn't worked

Comment: See the duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439461/ssh-default-port-not-changing-ubuntu-22-10

Answer (score -2):

You also need to change the port inside /etc/ssh/sshd_config, it would be

Port your_port_number

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 23