Alternatives of connecting to VM
I want to host my small discord bot on a virtual machine so it can run 7/24. I got a Linux VM on Azure via GitHub's Student Developer Pack. The problem is, I live in university dorm and I use university's internet. University doesn't allow others to connect to port 22 and because of this, I can't connect to my VM via SSH.
How can I transfer my code to VM so I can run my discord bot there without connecting to VM via SSH?

You can change the port the ssh service is listening on on the VM so that it listens on a port you can estabilish an outbound connection to: https://askubuntu.com/a/1439482/380067 (Ubuntu 22.10 and later)

@user68186 VM is on Microsoft's server. But I can't connect to it while being connected to University network

use a usb drive
